# Visual Studio 2017 - TFS Rollback

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

If I rollback someone else's changeset, is it only changed on my machine unless I check-in the rollback?
for example: I think my co-worker's change broke something so I roll it back.
After testing, I realize the rollback didn't fix anything.
Can I just undo the changes or did the rollback make changes on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless explicitly stated otherwise (such as when creating branches), the results of TFVC operations have to be checked in for them to be available to others. Rollbacks are no exception. If in doubt, look in the "pending changes" window.